# After updating to Xcode 12, I am getting 20 errors from GoogleDataTransport file named 'cct.nanopb.h'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12

After updating to Xcode 12, I am getting 20 errors from GoogleDataTransport in a file named 'cct.nanopb.h' - unknown type name .. with various names and then another 'Uncategorized' with 'Too many errors emitted, stopping now'

[image: unknown type name errors]

[image: uncategorized]

Comment: that pod is critical for your project any problem if you  just remove it ?

Comment: pod update GoogleDataTransport
try this one pls I wonder it works or not

Comment: Check answer below - seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went into **Project/Build Settings** and disabled 'Quoted Include In Framework Header'

[image]